# Remove leading dollar sign from data and improve current solution

Tags: python-3.x, regex

I have string like so:

*"Job 1233:name_uuid (table n_Cars_1234567$20220316) done. Records: 24, with errors: 0."*

I'd like to retieve the datte from the table name, so far I use:

```
"\$[0-9]+"
```

but this yields **$20220316**. How do I get only the date, without **$**?

I'd also like to get the table name: **n_Cars_12345678$20220316**

So far I have this:

```
pattern_table_info = "\(([^\)]+)\)"
pattern_table_name = "(?<=table ).*"

table_info = re.search(pattern_table_info, message).group(1)
table = re.search(pattern_table_name, table_info).group(0)
```

However I'd like to have a more simpler solution, how can I improve this?

**EDIT:**

Actually the table name should be:

n_Cars_12345678

So everything before the "$" sign and after "table"...how can this part of the string be retrieved?

Comment: For the date: use a positive look behind like this: `(?<=\$)[0-9]+`, which means "Find the first number in the string that has a `$` before it".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a single pattern with 2 capture groups:

```
\(table (\w+\$(\d+))\)
```

The pattern matches:

- `\(table`
- `(` Capture **group 1**

  - `\w+\$` match 1+ word characters and `$`
  - `(\d+)` Capture **group 2**, match 1+ digits
- `)` Close group 1
- `\)` Match `)`

See a [Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/fJ8seh/1) and a [Python demo](https://ideone.com/6lM1Qx).

```
import re

s = "Job 1233:name_uuid (table n_Cars_1234567$20220316) done. Records: 24, with errors: 0."
m = re.search(r"\(table (\w+\$(\d+))\)", s)
if m:
    print(m.group(1))
    print(m.group(2))
```

Output

```
n_Cars_1234567$20220316
20220316
```

Comment: thank you, I just updated the post as the table name required was incorrect.

Comment: @pymat You still get the same groups right, and group 1 having  `n_Cars_12345678` now https://regex101.com/r/xsn0NL/1

Comment: Group 1 yields: n_Cars_12345678$20220316, and what is required is only n_Cars_12345678

Comment: @pymat Then you can use 2 capture groups but not nested `\(table (\w+)\$(\d+)\)` https://regex101.com/r/GlyAQf/1

Answer (score 2):

You can use a regex with two capturing groups:

```
table\s+([^()]*)\$([0-9]+)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/2f7kpu/2). *Details*:

- `table` - a word
- `\s+` - one or more whitespaces
- `([^()]*)` - Group 1: zero or more chars other than `(` and `)`
- `\$` - a `$` char
- `([0-9]+)` - Group 2: one or more digits.

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/VKLooY):

```py
import re
text = "Job 1233:name_uuid (table n_Cars_1234567$20220316) done. Records: 24, with errors: 0."
rx = r"table\s+([^()]*)\$([0-9]+)"
m = re.search(rx, text)
if m:
    print(m.group(1))
    print(m.group(2))
```

Output:

```
n_Cars_1234567
20220316
```

Comment: thank you, I just updated the post as the table name required was incorrect.

Comment: @pymat Move the Group 1 closing parenthesis: `table\s+([^()]*)\$([0-9]+)`, see [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/2f7kpu/2).